# Primality Testing

Tags: c, math, primes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest primality test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493645/fastest-primality-test)

Can somebody give an efficient algorithm for determining the primality of an number?

The conventional iteration method seems to take a lot of time when testing primality of large numbers. I have tried some probabilistic algorithms but was not satisfied by the accuracy.

Comment: As far as I know, you will always have a trade off between accuracy and efficiency when you use a primality test. I have only used the [Miller Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), but I think you will have to more precises in what you are doing.

Comment: Also, just choose a sufficiently large k. 2^-k (or any n^-k for n > 1) gets small exponentially fast (read: VERY FAST).

Comment: Wow, there are a lot more duplicates than that - just search for primality test.

Answer (score 2):

On of the most efficient probabilistic primality tests is the [Rabin-Miller primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) ([implementation in C](http://en.literateprograms.org/Miller-Rabin_primality_test_%28C%29)). This is what RSA uses.

Deterministic tests are more difficult if you need speed and are seldomly useful in real world applications.