# Math behind gcc9+ modulus optimizations

Tags: c, math, compiler-optimization, modulus

**Background**

I was playing with prime numbers in c, when I stumbled upon a new optimization in gcc trunk (will be version 9.x) that optimizes a modulus comparison to 0 into an integer multiply and comparison using magic numbers.  In other words `x%prime==0` becomes `x*Magic_mul<=Magic_cmp`

```
_Bool mod(unsigned x){return x % Constant == 0;}

mod:
  imul edi, edi, Magic_mul
  cmp edi, Magic_cmp
  setbe al
```

**Details**

Based on seeing the asm output, it does these optimizations for all integers (well, primes at least)  I converted them to hex to help see the patterns, but its not immediately obvious at the moment.

```
//32bit examples for _Bool mod_n(unsigned x){return x%n==0;};
//note: parameter is unsigned but it becomes a signed multiply
x%3==0;  // x*0xAAAAAAAB <= 0x55555555
x%5==0;  // x*0xCCCCCCCD <= 0x33333333
x%7==0;  // x*0xB6DB6DB7 <= 0x24924924
x%11==0; // x*0xBA2E8BA3 <= 0x1745D174
x%13==0; // x*0xC4EC4EC5 <= 0x13B13B13
x%17==0; // x*0xF0F0F0F1 <= 0x0F0F0F0F
x%19==0; // x*0x286BCA1B <= 0x0D79435E
x%23==0; // x*0xE9BD37A7 <= 0x0B21642C
x%29==0; // x*0x4F72C235 <= 0x08D3DCB0
x%31==0; // x*0xBDEF7BDF <= 0x08421084
x%37==0; // x*0x914C1BAD <= 0x06EB3E45
x%41==0; // x*0xC18F9C19 <= 0x063E7063
x%43==0; // x*0x2FA0BE83 <= 0x05F417D0
x%47==0; // x*0x677D46CF <= 0x0572620A
x%53==0; // x*0x8C13521D <= 0x04D4873E
x%59==0; // x*0xA08AD8F3 <= 0x0456C797
x%61==0; // x*0xC10C9715 <= 0x04325C53
x%67==0; // x*0x07A44C6B <= 0x03D22635
x%71==0; // x*0xE327A977 <= 0x039B0AD1
x%73==0; // x*0xC7E3F1F9 <= 0x0381C0E0
x%79==0; // x*0x613716AF <= 0x033D91D2
x%83==0; // x*0x2B2E43DB <= 0x03159721
x%89==0; // x*0xFA3F47E9 <= 0x02E05C0B
x%97==0; // x*0x5F02A3A1 <= 0x02A3A0FD
///...and even up to 64bit
x%4294967291==0; //x*0x70A3D70A33333333 <= 0x100000005
```

I checked [hacker's delight "INTEGER DIVISION BY CONSTANTS"](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf) and it seems like this may be a special case of *remainder by multiplication and right shift*, but I'm not sure.  There is a [form on hacker's delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm) that calculates these same multiplier constants, so that seems promising.  I'm guessing the magic comparison constant replaces the shift and compare to zero, but I am having trouble visualizing the 2s complement and whether the shift is arithmetic or logical.

**Question**

Is there some math behind this or were the numbers determined some other way using the binary representation?

**Implications**

Since this is simple integer multiply and comparison this could drastically speed up (or reduce memory footprint of) checking for prime using vector extensions/intrinsics.  If the math could be extended beyond 64 bits, it could possibly make finding large Big-Number primes much faster?

Comment: [For division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Re implication: If you want to find larger primes, usually you just switch to a better primality check algorithm (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493645/fastest-primality-test), which doesn't have much to do with the main question.

Answer (score 3):

Take 3, for instance.

0xAB * 3 = 0x201, thus, modulo 0x100, 0xAB is 1 / 3, and, inversely, 0xAB * 3 ≡ 1.

Any 8-bit unsigned integer n can be represented as n = 3*k + r, r < 3, and k is at most 0x55 (decimal 85, integral part of 255 / 3).

So we have options:

1. r = 0 ⇒ n * 0xAB = 3k * 0xAB = k * (3 * 0xAB) ≡ k * 1 = k ≤ 0x55.
2. r = 1 ⇒ n * 0xAB = 3k * 0xAB + 0xAB; since 3k * 0xAB is at most 0x55 (mod 0x100), adding it to 0xAB won't overflow, so 3k * 0xAB + 0xAB ≥ 0xAB > 0x55.
3. r = 2 ⇒ n * 0xAB = 3k * 0xAB + 0x156 ≡ 3k * 0xAB + 0x56 ≥ 0x56 > 0x55 (same as 2.)

Comment: Your math looks sound and seems to follow with the other documentation of this concept.  I think I just need to grind out a few examples in binary notation to follow it (or get some sleep so I can do the hex->binary in my head).  I was also hoping to figure out the math to get the comparison constants (which may be obvious once I can visualize it)

Comment: Well, constants are quite straightforward, 0xAB is simply 1/3 and 0x55 is the highest floor of n/3 for a 8-bit n. Implications follow. :)