# How do I make this C code run faster on determining whether a large number is a prime number or not?

Tags: c, performance, primes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

bool isPrime(long long int n) {
    if(n <= 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for(long long int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
            if(n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    
    int cases;
    long long int num;
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        scanf("%lld", &num);
        if(isPrime(num)) {
            printf("YES\n");
        } else {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way I could do to make this code run faster? I tried the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm but that was slower, and apparently this "try to divide a number from 2 to its square root" is faster, but not fast enough according to the online judge.

Comment: Define "faster".

Comment: You call the `sqrt()` function for every loop, you could just call it once, store the result in an integer and compare it with that integer. Do you enable compiler optimizations?

Comment: You can make it twice as fast by starting at 3 and incrementing by two (you have to handle %2 outside the loop).

Comment: How big will `cases` and `num` be? When `num` is a prime number near `10**18`, the loop will run about `10**9` times and it will be too much for typical online judge system. My guess is you should use the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm because you have to process multiple queries.

Comment: Why do you use `signed`? Would `unsigned` not be more suitable and maybe a tiny bit faster?

Comment: The most basic improvement is indeed to only check odd numbers. You can check the thousands of other prime numbers posts present on SO for inspiration.

Comment: If the input is small enough, you could embed all the primes below a threshold in a hardcoded array so you only have to test for them. So it is relevant how large the largest input will be.

Comment: According to the online judge, the input (N) will be somewhere between [2 <= N <= 2^63-1].

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493645/fastest-primality-test

Comment: Please give a look to more advanced algorithms like the [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) which should much faster for your problem.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I tried that, while it is definitely faster, it's not as accurate as I'd hoped it to be.

Comment: @baronoke Note that the test can be tuned to be deterministic (assuming the Riemann hypothesis is true)

Comment: @baronoke You can use the Miller-Rabin test to exclude numbers that are not prime. The numbers you have left, which should be a small amount, can be checked with the algorithm you already use.

Comment: Re: `I tried the Sieve of Eratosthenes` - did you build it once? Or for each case?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I built it once, right after int main() {

Comment: Did you use its result in your `isPrime`? Can you show your code? That should be OK for the performance.

Comment: There will be about 139094145 prime numbers below `sqrt(2**63)==2**31.5`, you could store them. It is about 550 MB. For numbers smaller than `2**31.5` check if they are in the list for larger numbers check if it is dividable by any of them. But i do not know if the online judge will accept a program that needs > 500 MB of RAM.